# Qt connection Sql Server (universal connection string)

Tags: c++, database, sql-server, qt

I am developing a software  to connect to sql server. The problem is, ¿i don't know wich sql server is used?, and my question is ¿if exist a universal connection String?.

I read many cases and in most, this is the string used:

```
 QString stringConnection="DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=local;UID=sad;PWD=soc; WSID=.";
```

Obviously, the user and password changes, and is possible a Sql Server running as instance, in this case i should add "\nameInstance" to field Server.

```
 QString stringConnection="DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost\\server2008;DATABASE=local;UID=sad;PWD=soc; WSID=."
```

¿can i use this string connection in all versions of Sql Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **need** to Allow for the user to configure the connection string.

**FYI:** To get around you password issue use integrated security.

```
"Driver={SQLServer};Server=localhost; Database=local; Trusted_Connection=yes;"
```

Comment: yes, i know, have contemplated the task. I ask because i read other strings and i don't sure ¿if the this works in all sql servers?.  Thanks for the tip for security.